# PHP & FTP: Getting latest batch of files

Tags: php, html, ftp

I have a FTP server containing 4000 or so pictures, to which get added on a regular basis by two seperate camera's (one pair of pictures per 30 minutes). I also have a website which displays these pictures.

Right now the website displays the latest 20 pictures from each camera. The pictures of the first camera all contain the string "House" and those of the second contain "Street". Here is the code I'm using right now:

```
$ftpConn = ftp_connect([LOGIN_INFORMATION]);
$login = ftp_login($ftpConn,[LOGIN_INFORMATION]);
if ((!$ftpConn) || (!$login)) {
    echo 'FTP connection has failed! Attempted to connect to '. $host. ' for user '.$user.'.';
    ftp_close($ftpConn);
    exit();
}

$directory = ftp_nlist($ftpConn,'');
$house = array();
$street = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < count($directory); $i++) {
    if (strpos($directory[$i], 'House')) {
        array_push($house, $directory[$i]);
    } else {
        array_push($street, $directory[$i]);
    }
}
$_SESSION['house'] = $house;
$_SESSION['street'] = $street;
ftp_close($ftpConn);
$result = "<ul>";
for ($i = count($house) - 6; $i < count($house); $i++) {
    $result .= "<li><a class=\"fancybox\" rel=\"group\" href=\"ftp://[LOGIN_INFORMATION]/$house[$i]\"><img src=\"ftp://LOGIN_INFORMATION/$house[$i]\" width=\"160\" height=\"90\" ></a></li>";
}
```

I have the feeling that first retrieving all of the files from the server to then only use 40 or so pictures is pretty inefficient. I have searched other methods of retrieving files based on date, but all of these methods seem to use the same technique of retrieving every single file before sorting them.

Am I doing it correctly or is there some kind of other way that would be more efficient?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like you are exposing your FTP credentials to the end user!

Comment: ftp_nlist just give you the names of the files, not the files themselves. This should not be a problem and there is no other way to do this as FTP does not support any filtering on the server. And, as noted above, do not put your credentials in the output html.

Comment: That's another problem I'm facing. Would you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In FTP, there's no way to retrieve a list of just a subset of files (matching certain criteria). Except that some servers allow selecting files based on a file mask (but that's not a standard).

So what you do, is the best you can do.